# Grouping by key value property in List of dict python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, filter

I have `orig` list of tuples that comprises `dict` & `text` values.

```
orig = [({'x': 28.346, 'y': 19},'Text0'),
 ({'x': 109.726, 'y': 19},'Text1'),
 ({'x': 147.776, 'y': 19},'Text2'),
 ({'x': 153.606, 'y': 24}, 'Text3'),
 ({'x': 452.788, 'y': 24}, 'Text4'),
 ({'x': 504.168, 'y': 34}, 'Text5'),
 ({'x': 527.768, 'y': 34}, 'Text6'),
 ({'x': 533.598, 'y': 45},'Text7'),
 ({'x': 64.291, 'y': 55},'Text8'),
 ({'x': 98.623, 'y': 55},'Text9')]
```

and I want to filter group from the `key='y'` in the which would give me list it according to unique values in `y`. Something like following:

```
res = [
      [({'x': 28.346, 'y': 19},'Text0'),
         ({'x': 109.726, 'y': 19},'Text1'),
         ({'x': 147.776, 'y': 19},'Text2')],
     [({'x': 153.606, 'y': 24}, 'Text3'),
         ({'x': 452.788, 'y': 24}, 'Text4')],
     [({'x': 504.168, 'y': 34}, 'Text5'),
         ({'x': 527.768, 'y': 34}, 'Text6')],
     [({'x': 533.598, 'y': 45},'Text7')],
     [({'x': 64.291, 'y': 55},'Text8'),
         ({'x': 98.623, 'y': 55},'Text9')]]
```

Comment: why the value of y is not unique in the first item of the list. 'y' is having values 19, 24, 34, 45, whereas in the second item 'y' is unique has only 55

Comment: updated the Question.

Comment: There are two items in the 'res' main list, the value of y is not unique in the first item of the main list `[({'x': 28.346, 'y': 19},'Text0'),
         ({'x': 109.726, 'y': 19},'Text1'),
         ({'x': 147.776, 'y': 19},'Text2'),
         ({'x': 153.606, 'y': 24}, 'Text3'),
         ({'x': 452.788, 'y': 24}, 'Text4'),
         ({'x': 504.168, 'y': 34}, 'Text5'),
         ({'x': 527.768, 'y': 34}, 'Text6'),
         ({'x': 533.598, 'y': 45},'Text7')]`. I hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `numpy` it will be bit easier.

```
import numpy as np
orig = [({'x': 28.346, 'y': 19}, 'Text0'),
        ({'x': 109.726, 'y': 19}, 'Text1'),
        ({'x': 147.776, 'y': 19}, 'Text2'),
        ({'x': 153.606, 'y': 24}, 'Text3'),
        ({'x': 452.788, 'y': 24}, 'Text4'),
        ({'x': 504.168, 'y': 34}, 'Text5'),
        ({'x': 527.768, 'y': 34}, 'Text6'),
        ({'x': 533.598, 'y': 45}, 'Text7'),
        ({'x': 64.291, 'y': 55}, 'Text8'),
        ({'x': 98.623, 'y': 55}, 'Text9')]


input_array = np.array([val[0]['y'] for val in orig])
out_array = [np.where(input_array == element)[0].tolist() for element in np.unique(input_array)]
res = [[orig[i] for i in ind_arr] for ind_arr in out_array]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[({'x': 28.346, 'y': 19}, 'Text0'),
  ({'x': 109.726, 'y': 19}, 'Text1'),
  ({'x': 147.776, 'y': 19}, 'Text2')],
 [({'x': 153.606, 'y': 24}, 'Text3'),
    ({'x': 452.788, 'y': 24}, 'Text4')],
 [({'x': 504.168, 'y': 34}, 'Text5'),
    ({'x': 527.768, 'y': 34}, 'Text6')],
 [({'x': 533.598, 'y': 45}, 'Text7')],
 [({'x': 64.291, 'y': 55}, 'Text8'),
    ({'x': 98.623, 'y': 55}, 'Text9')]]
```

Comment: No. I want list with unique values of `y` in the list.

Comment: can you share your desired output, i guess in the question it looks confusing

Comment: I have update the question. `orig` is `list` type where as `res` as `list` of `list`. Based on the unique values of `y`.

Comment: why the value of y is not unique in the first item of the list. 'y' is having values 19, 24, 34, 45, whereas in the second item 'y' is unique has only 55

Comment: Wow. That Is great answer with using `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

**A two-liner solution using `itertools.groupby` and `list comprehension`:**

```
from itertools import groupby
# group by the input orig with a key of dict "y" and then take it in a list of list comprehension
print ([[x for x in v] for k, v in groupby(orig, key= lambda x: x[0]["y"])])
```

Result:

```
[[({'x': 28.346, 'y': 19}, 'Text0'), ({'x': 109.726, 'y': 19}, 'Text1'), ({'x': 147.776, 'y': 19}, 'Text2')], [({'x': 153.606, 'y': 24}, 'Text3'), ({'x': 452.788, 'y': 24}, 'Text4')], [({'x': 504.168, 'y': 34}, 'Text5'), ({'x': 527.768, 'y': 34}, 'Text6')], [({'x': 533.598, 'y': 45}, 'Text7')], [({'x': 64.291, 'y': 55}, 'Text8'), ({'x': 98.623, 'y': 55}, 'Text9')]]
```

I hope this counts :)

Comment: That's savage. Thanks.